# how to exclude image while saving Rss Feed In dataBase and need to show full Feed Description in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

while i am saving RssFeed in Database all Fields are saving like link,Id etc but coming to Description it saving only smalldescription  until image Src coming and stopping there onwards.i just want to Ignore image and need to save full Description and show in my page.i am showing Rss Feed in Repeater control i will post my code here thanks in advance

aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RSSFeed.aspx.cs" Inherits="RSSFeed" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="blog_bg">
        <%--  <asp:Label ID="lblBlogOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="TitleHyperLink" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Link") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<%--</br><asp:HyperLink ID="MoreHyperLink" runat="server">See More...</asp:HyperLink></p>--%>
                    <div id="divdesc">
                    <asp:Label ID="PublishedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Published") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SmallDescription") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<%--<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/NewsFeedinfo.aspx?RssId={0}">See More...</asp:HyperLink>--%>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "NewsFeedinfo.aspx?RssId=" + Eval("RssID") %>' >See More...</asp:HyperLink>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

public partial class RSSFeed : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    RssDC rssDC = new RssDC();
    RssBAL rssBAL = new RssBAL();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BlogFeeds("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_americas.rss", 3);
        BlogFeeds("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#", 3);
        BlogFeeds("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/Election2012", 3);

        fillRssFeeds();

    }



    private void fillRssFeeds()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = rssBAL.GetRssFeeds(rssDC);

        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void BlogFeeds(string url, int count)
    {

        try
        {

            RssDC rssDC = new RssDC();
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList items = default(XmlNodeList);
            xmldoc.Load(url);
            items = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");
            int i = 0;
            // use XPath to get only items

            foreach (XmlNode item1 in items)
            {
                int currentIterationIndex = 0;
                foreach (XmlNode node1 in item1.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (currentIterationIndex == count - 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }


                    if (node1.Name == "title")
                    {
                        rssDC.Title = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "link")
                    {
                        rssDC.Link = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "guid")
                    {
                        rssDC.RSS_ID = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "description")
                    {
                        rssDC.Description = node1.InnerText;
                    }
                    else if (node1.Name == "pubDate")
                    {
                        rssDC.DatePublished = node1.InnerText;


                    }
                    currentIterationIndex += 1;


                }
                rssDC = RssBAL.AddRssFeed(rssDC);
                i++;

                if (i == 3)
                    break;

            }



        }
        catch (Exception eax)
        {
            //return;
        }

        //return rssFeedList;
        //Repeater1.DataSource = rssFeedList;
        //Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asp:Label and use <%# Eval("Description") %> without it.